# Traefik TLS termination. Client(HTTPS)-[TRAEFIK(HTTPS) <-> TRAEFIK(HTTP)]-REACT(HTTP)

Tags: reactjs, docker, https, proxy, traefik

I have a web app in Docker:

FRONT
react

BACK
laravel-echo-server
nginx
redis
php-fpm
......

To work with it i go to 127.0.0.1:5000(FRONT-react port) and everything fine.It sends requests to the backend, nginx manages them.

Now I need to add HTTPS and working in VDS. In fact, I need reverse-proxy. My application does not know how to work over https, so the logic of work for it should not change, it should think that it works over http with itself. But at the same time, it needs to stick out and work in the browser via HTTPS.

I try to place Traefik to FRONT to 80 port/

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

volumes:
  react:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  traefik:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}

services:

  ### react #####################################################
  react:
    image: ${REGISTRY_URL}/react
    ports:
      - "5000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - REACT_APP_SCHEME=${REACT_APP_SCHEME}
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT=${REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT}
      - REACT_APP_LARAVEL_ECHO_PORT=${REACT_APP_LARAVEL_ECHO_PORT}
      - REACT_CLIENT_ID=${REACT_CLIENT_ID}
      - REACT_CLIENT_SECRET=${REACT_CLIENT_SECRET}
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.https.entrypoints=https
      #- traefik.http.routers.https.tls=true
      #- traefik.http.routers.https.tls.certresolver=${CERT_RESOLVER}
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    restart: always
    
      ### traefik #####################################################
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command:

      # Be careful in production as it exposes the traffic you might not want to expose.
      #--log.level=DEBUG

      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443

      - --providers.docker=true

      - --api=true

      # LetsEncrypt Staging Server - uncomment when testing
      # - --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.caServer=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=http
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=${EMAIL}
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
    labels:
      # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.to-https.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.to-https.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.to-https.middlewares=to-https

      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.${DOMAIN}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=auth
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=${CERT_RESOLVER}

      - traefik.http.middlewares.to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https

    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./data/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    restart: always
```

OR i try using this config

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  trfk:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

volumes:
  react:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  traefik:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}

services:

  ### react #####################################################
  react:
    image: ${REGISTRY_URL}/react
    ports:
      - "5000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - REACT_APP_SCHEME=${REACT_APP_SCHEME}
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT=${REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT}
      - REACT_APP_LARAVEL_ECHO_PORT=${REACT_APP_LARAVEL_ECHO_PORT}
      - REACT_CLIENT_ID=${REACT_CLIENT_ID}
      - REACT_CLIENT_SECRET=${REACT_CLIENT_SECRET}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.react.rule=Host(`MYDOMAIN.COM`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.react.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.react.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
      - trfk
    restart: always
    
      ### traefik #####################################################
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
#- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=*MYEMAIL*"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"     
    ports:
#      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - trfk
    restart: always
```

My docker-compose here.

Now when i try in Mozilla HTTP, everything fine with IP or domain.
But when i try HTTPS(dont disable in Mozilla) my backend sends errors.
Apparently he tries to work on https too. It's like a redirect, but not a reverse proxy.

What should I do so that my Traefik will stand in front of React and only accept requests on 443, and then send them to react on port 5000 over HTTP? Client(HTTPS)-TRAEFIK(HTTPS) <-> TRAEFIK(HTTP)-REACT(HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the part in the config, where traefik knows to direct the request to. You configured traefik to query the docker API so it knows which container and ports are existing, but it doesn't know that the requests should go to the react container. Add either this label to the react container

```
- traefik.http.routers.https.service=react@docker
```

or:

```
- traefik.http.services.CHOSEN_NAME.loadbalancer.server.port=5000
```

The first one is the better solution, as it dynamically fetches the port of the react container listening.